# Can I share a wifi connection from USB on a Mac via Airport?

Tags: mac, networking, wireless-networking, macbook, wifi-driver

That is, I'd like to use something [like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002VVITG8) to achieve `wifi network -> USB adapter -> MacBook Air -> shared via wifi`  I can't share my Airport connection via Airport, but I was wondering if I can share a wifi connection from USB via Airport?

But, before I go ahead and purchase an adapter, I wanted to confirm that this was possible.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'd try to find out if something that small was weaker than the normal sized wireless usb drives. IMO small is gimmicky for those types of things, though it may be important with a laptop, here's some more http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/bestsellers/computers/430581031/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_computers_1_3_last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac seems to let you share any type of network out, so there is no reason why not. Also, as the Macbook Air gets its wired internet by USB, it seems even more likely that they have tested this and deliberately included it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, are you trying to share out wifi with others from your mac using a broadband device?  A simpler approach is to use a "mi-fi" device which shares out like a wireless router and connects to 3G or 4G.  Then you and others can connect to it like any other wireless router.

Comment: That's expensive and only a few countries.

Answer (score -1):

this was helpful for me as I use usb wifi adapter
http://bearextender.com/doc/manual/Optimization/airport-range-extender-mode.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.